# Как отправить запрос через proxy?

Tags: node.js

У меня есть **proxy** адрес, который выглядит примерно так: `185.233.80.131 : 9122 : GVF7nV : kbh32Z (ip адрес : порт : логин : пароль)`. Для отправки запроса через **proxy** я использую **Tunnel**.

```
const tunnelingAgent = tunnel.httpOverHttps({
  proxy: getProxyOptions(),
});

const req = https.request(
  {
    host: 'url сайта, к которому хочу обратиться через proxy',
    port: 443,
    agent: tunnelingAgent,
  },
  (res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }
);

function getProxyOptions() {
  return {
    host: '185.233.80.131',
    port: 9122,
    proxyAuth: 'GVF7nV:kbh32Z'
  };
}
```

Но вылетает **ошибка:**

```
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 12248:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332
```

Судя по ответам в интернете, такая ошибка говорит об использовании в адресе **https**, в то время как при обращении к **proxy** нужно использовать **http**.

**Но когда пытаюсь записать примерно вот так:**

```
function getProxyOptions() {
  return {
    host: 'http://185.233.80.131',
    port: 9122,
    proxyAuth: 'GVF7nV:kbh32Z'
  };
}
```

**Выдаёт ошибку:**

```
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 185.233.80.131
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

**UPDATE:**
Если считать проблемой то, что я не мог отправить запрос через proxy, то эту проблему я решил. Для этого я использовал библиотеку **node-fetch**. Теперь отправление запроса выглядит так:

```
import * as url from 'url';
import fetch, { RequestInit } from 'node-fetch';
import { Agent } from 'http';

const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

const agentOptions: url.UrlWithStringQuery = url.parse('http://185.233.80.131:9122');
agentOptions.auth = 'GVF7nV:kbh32Z';

const agent: Agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(agentOptions);
const requestInit: RequestInit = { agent };

fetch('https://example.com', requestInit);
```

Comment: этот сервис точно рабочий? `telnet 185.233.80.131 9122 Trying 185.233.80.131... telnet: connect to address 185.233.80.131: Connection refused telnet: Unable to connect to remote host` `nmap 185.233.80.131 -p 9122  PORT     STATE  SERVICE 9122/tcp closed grcmp`

Comment: Мой сервис точно рабочий. В вопросе, если что, указан не он.)

Comment: вы не даёте участникам ru.so возможность повторить вашу проблему, т.о. вам смогут помочь гугл, большой so и те участники ru.so, кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой (за 6 часов таких не нашлось)